# How to access the scope properties of nested Angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having an issue accessing the scope of an inner directive in Angular.

I have created two directives, an inner directive, and an outer directive.  I want them both to have isolate scope.  I want the inner directive to be an attribute on a form tag, and I want the function on the inner directive's scope to be called when the form is submitted.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work.

Why can I not access the doThing function on the inner directive?  Also, if I change the innerDirective to be scope: false, I can't access to outer directive's doSomething function.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

http://codepen.io/justinbc820/pen/vNBWMp

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('outerDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.doThing = function() {
              alert('outer directive');
            }
        }
    };
})
.directive('innerDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.doThing = function() {
                alert('inner directive');
            }
        }
    };
});


<div ng-app="app">
  <outer-directive>

    <form inner-directive ng-submit="doThing()">
      <button type="submit">Do THING</button>
    </form>

  </outer-directive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope.$parent in innerDirective as below.

```
.directive('innerDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$parent.doThing = function() {
          alert('inner directive');          
        }
       }
};
```